# How Can I Send Emails To Registered Members in MyDatabase?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm Using `Sql Server 2008`.

I've a created a database named "Sankal_Residency"

There is a Table named `"Member_Details"` in which I have stored all members `Email Id`.

So now I want to send them Mail (LIke .Pdf, .Doc,) or any simple message like new letter
for a selected persons and also all the registered members.

How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure to send e-mail.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

You first need to create a profile and account for sending e-mails.
The account would be associated to profile and the profile is used as a parameter while sending e-mail.

The basic parameters that you will need to provide are:

1. @profile_name: Name of the profile that you have created in Database Mail
2. @recipients: If you want to include all recipients in a single e-mail, use semi-colon separated e-mail IDs
3. @subject: The subject of e-mail
4. @body: The content of e-mail

Depending on content of e-mail and attachments, you may want to use @body_format and @file_attachments parameters.

In order to create Database Mail profile and accounts, refer to the following link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187605.aspx

Comment: I'm a Novice to this technology. Can you Please Explain me in details with step by step?

Comment: Alright, Got Something now.. Can you Please make a simple example for me to study it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are preferring the ASP.NET for sending emails, this link would be useful for it: http://hightechnology.in/how-to-send-multiple-emails-from-database-in-asp-net-using-c/

Tutorial in above link will send email to email addresses stored in the database one by one using `foreach` loop.

And if you want to attach the file with the email, simply use Attachment collection like this:

```
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/image.jpg")));
```

In above example, I have attach a file called "image.jpg", located in the root of the ASP.NET website. By this method, you can attach multiple files with one email.